# ¿Como modificar los resultados obtenido de sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

Cuando hago la consulta los datos se me guardan tal que asi:

`consulta = "SELECT moneda_to FROM movimientos"`

`proba= dbManager.consultaSQL(consulta)`

`proba = {'moneda_to': 'XLM'}`

Como puedo hacer que los datos se guarden así:
`proba = 'XLM'`

Gracias!!!!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta poner esta linea en lugar de la primera asignación de la variable "proba"

proba= dbManager.consultaSQL(consulta)['moneda_to']